# Dynamic app button

Tags: android, android-button

I want to create a button like we have in WhatsApp for using microphone to record speech.

Basically, if user starts to type something  then that microphone button converts into send text button .However, if user deletes the text then that button again changes to microphone button. Can anyone please tell me how to create a button like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `TextWatcher` to detect when the `EditText`'s content has been changed and perform your desired action.

Example:

```
yourEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        //called after the EditText's text is changed

        if (editable.length() > 0) {
            //change to send message icon
        } else {
            //change to microphone icon
        }
    }
});
```

For your button's `onClickListener`, just perform a check whether the `EditText` is empty or not.

Example:

```
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        String text = yourEditText.getText().toString();
        if (text.isEmpty()) {
            //perform your microphone action
        } else {
            //perform your send message action
        }
    }
});
```